# PHP execute issue in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, attributes, customer, custom

I'm trying to save my custom customer attribute when the corresponding checkbox is checked.

But if the customer unchecks the checkbox it should update the attribute to a value of 0.

```
var newProducts = $('#new_products');
$('input[type="checkbox"').on('click',function () {
    if (newProducts.is(':checked')) {
        <?php
            $customer->getCustomAttribute("new_products_attr")->setValue(1);
            $customerRepository->save($customer);
        ?>
    }
});
```

The problem I have is PHP runs before the jQuery, I could do an ajax call but then how am I supposed to access the variables needed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run the php code. if you want to update the customer attribute use ajax.

```
<script> require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php  echo $block->getUrl(helloworld/ajax/index); ?>",
          data: { q: "test"},
          dataType: "json"
        })
      .done(function( msg ) {

        //do something with you return data


      });
    }
});
```

Controller code

```
<?php namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Controller\Ajax;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
class Index extends Action {
protected $request;
public function __construct(Context $context,array $data = [])
{
parent::__construct($context,$data);
}
public function __execute() {
    $data=array("bdfb");
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($data);
    return $resultJson;

}
}
```

[Reference](https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-jquery-ajax-request/)